# Pushing value to array return non-iterable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

I  have a function which fetches data from the database and sets them in an array. But the issue here is that the array created here returns an array object with length 0

my Code

```
let products = [];
item.order_items.map((x) => {
  Axios.get(api + `/order-items/${x.id}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + user.token,
    },
  }).then((res) => products.push(res.data.product));
});
console.log(products);
```

This returns 
[image]

which makes the array non-iterable... Is there any fix for this

Comment: It's not quite clear. Even if it's an empty object, how would that make the array non-iterable?

Comment: The console.log shows length:3.  Is it because of async?  Are you trying to manipulate the array before it's been populated?

Comment: It seems to be async events not yet resolved. Isn't this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930001/javascript-array-not-iterable

Comment: The problem here is that the array is populated with the value but can not run array.map on it as the _proto_: array(0)

Comment: I am manipulating the array after it's been populated by the async function. The line where it runs console.log -> array.length returns 0